# Package does not exist on attached library/module/dependency

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have added the external library as a module.

My problem is: [mixed screenshots describing the problem and situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUOHX.png) Main app activities don't see these external classes, symbols. Can't even import them with alt+enter, no option here.

Downloaded this https://github.com/jeancsanchez/JcPlayer as zip. Then put in /libs directory unpacked. Where `/` is root directory of the whole project.

Tried to add it using this guide from other topic

```
Android Studio works on project-modules concept,All your modules should be inside a root directory(Your Project Directory). One module can be depended on other module/modules. Your libraries are considered as different modules under same project and your main module(app in your case) depends on them.

Change your project structure a little bit :

Project Root
+-- libs
    +-- PullToRefresh (my lib project)
+-- app
|   +-- builds
|   +-- src
|   |   +-- main (java code and resources)
    +-- .....
+--settings.gradle
Include this line in your settings.gradle

include ':libs:PullToRefresh'
Your build.gradle looks fine. I suggest you to change your directory name from libs to library because use libs for your jar dependency not for module dependencies.

and keep this in your main module's build.gradle file :

dependencies {
    compile project(":libs:PullToRefresh")
}
```

But unfortunately `compile project(":libs:PullToRefresh")` didn't work for me. `implementation project(":libs:PullToRefresh")` didn't work too.

Only `releaseImplementation project(':libs:jcplayer')` worked.

This is my problem for now: [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8u7n1.png)

I tried to do Invalidate Cache.

Rebuild project.

Sync project with gradle files

I do not know what to do. Really. + I am weak android developer

---

By following this tutorial `https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio`
got the

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKmYB.png

Comment: Which android studio version you are using right now?
I think its android studio version related issue.

Comment: @MaheshKeshvala Android Studio 3.3.1

Comment: its module project right? then why are you put that into the libs.
According to my knowledge libs contains only jar files.

Comment: Please follow below steps if you want to add module project manually into the android studio:

https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio

Comment: @MaheshKeshvala its just named libs. I can name this directory however I want to. But I think yes it's a module/project/library whole with gradle files etc

Comment: Please follow github steps

Comment: @MaheshKeshvala don't fully understand the `gradle clean & build/close the project and reopen/re-import it.`
You mean to do `Build->Clean` Project + `File->Re-import`?

Comment: @MaheshKeshvala did exactly as u said, with this tutorial and got the `https://imgur.com/a/LTSEbWY`

Comment: use this `implementation 'com.github.jeancsanchez:JcPlayer:{version}'` in build.gradel module file

Comment: @DurgeshKumar but I had that before. But I want to use the downloaded version. Because I need to edit some layouts of this library

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library
follow this link may be it will help
check this line "Make sure the library is listed at the top of your settings.gradle file, as shown here for a library named "my-library-module":"